# APIs para reconocimiento de Voz por Java

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo un proyecto en mente el cual necesita procesamiento de voz, Quisiera saber que librerias me recomiendan para el procesamiento y reconocimiento de voz por Java.

Comment: Hola @AsahiSara. Por favor evita las preguntas que soliciten recomendaciones de software o librerías puesto que son muy subjetivas para el propósito de este sitio. Podrías intentar ese tipo de preguntas en http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (en inglés, lastimosamente). Recuerda leer las reglas del sitio antes de publicar una pregunta.

Comment: Esta bien, solo que el problema de preguntar por alguna la api de reconocimiento de voz por un sitio en ingles, me recomendaran una api que solo procese ingles. Por eso lo preguntaba aqui.

Comment: Podrías indicar si la librería soporta más idiomas que el inglés, no creo que eso haga que la pregunta se cierre.

Comment: Buen punto, lo preguntare asi, solo que me preocupo por la calidad que tenga esa libreria en Español, porque si su idioma principal es Ingles la libreria en español puede ser menos eficiente (Eso siempre pasa en caso de no ser el idioma principal) pero estoy buscando una libreria que soporte español a una calidad buena.

Comment: Yo he probado una en Android que es propia de Google para procesar español y funcionaba para lo que necesitaba. No sé si esa librería se pueda utilizar fuera de Android.

Comment: Encontre una que se llama **CMU Sphinx**, espero que este en español.